# BigQuery apply function over many columns in groupby

Tags: google-bigquery

**EDIT:** I have updating the question with a simpler example using a table without `STRUCT`s

I come from an R background where the `apply` family of functions makes it incredibly easy to apply a function over multiple columns at once. In the updated example below, I have a table with multiple "pctile" columns, with numbers ranging from 1 - 100 in these columns:

```
WITH 
  wide_stats AS (
    SELECT 
      'joe' name, 'bills' team, false as is_o,
      7 as stat1, 95 as stat1_pctile, 
      9 as stat2, 82 as stat2_pctile, 
      3 as stat3, 67 as stat3_pctile
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 
      'joe', 'bills', true as is_o,
      1 as stat1, 37 as stat1_pctile,
      5 as stat2, 54 as stat2_pctile,
      2 as stat3, 17 as stat3_pctile
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 
      'tim' name, 'jets' team, false as is_o,
      17 as stat1, 65 as stat1_pctile,
      12 as stat2, 85 as stat2_pctile,
      13 as stat3, 69 as stat3_pctile
    UNION ALL
    SELECT
      'tim' name, 'jets' team, true as is_o,
      15 as stat1, 32 as stat1_pctile,
      14 as stat2, 56 as stat2_pctile,
      12 as stat3, 16 as stat3_pctile
  )

 SELECT * FROM wide_stats
```

To each column that ends in `_pctile`, I would like to run the function `if(is_o, 100 - col_val, col_val)`, that simply (a) checks if the `is_o` column is true, and (b) if true, then do `100 - col_val` on whatever value is already in the column, otherwise leave the column unchanged. I would like to achieve this without having to manually write this code out for each column ending in `_pctile`, as i have 100+ of these in my actual, very wide data.

Any help on this would be greatly appreciated! Although this is BQ instead of R, this type of `apply` functionality would help me significantly with my task at hand.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, you are paying the price for not optimal schema you chosen to use

The only option I see here is to flatten  your data such that each key(stat1, stat2, stat3, etc) is on separate row as in example below (BigQuery Standard SQL)

```
#standardSQL
SELECT * REPLACE(IF(is_o, 100 - value_pctile, value_pctile) AS value_pctile)
FROM (
  SELECT name, team, is_o, 
    REPLACE(SPLIT(kv, '":')[OFFSET(0)], '_pctile', '') key, 
    CAST(REGEXP_EXTRACT(TO_JSON_STRING(t), CONCAT(r'"', REPLACE(SPLIT(kv, '":')[OFFSET(0)], '_pctile', ''), r'":(\d+),')) AS INT64) value,
    SPLIT(kv, '":')[OFFSET(0)] key_pctile, 
    CAST(SPLIT(kv, '":')[OFFSET(1)] AS INT64) value_pctile
  FROM wide_stats t, UNNEST(REGEXP_EXTRACT_ALL(TO_JSON_STRING(t), r'"(\w+_pctile":\d+),')) kv
)
```

if to apply to sample data from your question - result is

```
Row name    team    is_o    key     value   key_pctile      value_pctile     
1   joe     bills   false   stat1   7       stat1_pctile    95   
2   joe     bills   false   stat2   9       stat2_pctile    82   
3   joe     bills   true    stat1   1       stat1_pctile    63   
4   joe     bills   true    stat2   5       stat2_pctile    46   
5   tim     jets    false   stat1   17      stat1_pctile    65   
6   tim     jets    false   stat2   12      stat2_pctile    85   
7   tim     jets    true    stat1   15      stat1_pctile    68   
8   tim     jets    true    stat2   14      stat2_pctile    44
```

As you can see, if you would have your table flattened to start with - the query would be as simple as

```
#standardSQL
SELECT * REPLACE(IF(is_o, 100 - value_pctile, value_pctile) AS value_pctile)
FROM flattened_table
```

Note: for all practical purposes - you anyway will need to flatten whatever result you need otherwise you constantly be facing same very issue like this one!